# BAD_ACCES iterator on map c++

Tags: c++, loops, dictionary, iterator, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to implement a function using a map in a map like that :

```
typedef std::map<int, float> inner_map;
typedef std::map<int, inner_map> outer_map;
```

I'm filling the map this way. The idea is the first map contains a int key and an other map which contains another key and a float. If the pair I obtain is known, I increment the value otherwise I fill the map.

```
for (int y = 2; y < imgSize.y - 2; y++){
    for (int x = 2; x < imgSize.x - 2; x++) {
        thisPos = x + y*imgSize.x ;

        {SOME CODE}

        lj = labelMap[thisPos] ;

        if (condition) {
            // get the 2 label 
            li = pro_label_mod[thisPos] ; 

            // look if it lj is in the map 
            is_lj = pi_matrix.count(lj) ;

            // this lj has already been observed 
            if (is_lj == 1) {
                is_li = pi_matrix[lj].count(li);

                // this pair is known -> I increment 
                if (is_li==1) {
                    pi_matrix[lj][li] +=  1.0f ;
                }
                else {
                     pi_matrix.at(lj).insert(pi_matrix[lj].end(), std::make_pair(li, 1.0f)) ;
                }
            }
            else {
                inner_map inter ; inter.insert(std::make_pair(li, 1.0f)) ;
                pi_matrix.emplace(lj, inter) ;
            }
        }
        numb_lj[lj] += 1.0f ;
    }
}
```

And then, I would like to iterate throught the map in my code. I did that with iterators such as :

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,float> > max_pi(size_lj) ;

float maxValue, thisValue ; int label_max ; 

for (outer_map::iterator it_lj = pi_matrix.begin(), it_lj_end = pi_matrix.end(); it_lj != it_lj_end; ++it_lj) {
    maxValue = 0.0f ;
    label_max = 0 ;

    inner_map &innerMap = it_lj->second;

    for(inner_map::iterator it_li = innerMap.begin(), it_li_end = innerMap.end(); it_li != it_li_end; ++it_li) {
        thisValue = it_li->second / numb_lj[it_lj->first] ;

        if (thisValue >= maxValue) {
            maxValue = thisValue ;
            label_max = it_li->first ;
        }
    }

    max_pi[it_lj->first] = std::make_pair(label_max, maxValue) ;
    i+=1;
}
```

However, i'm getting a segmentation fault at the lines of the for loop (either the first one or the second one). BUT ! Not every time. I'm calling this function at each frame and I can have 5 calls without a BAD_ACCESS and suddenly, it crashes.. Sometimes after the first call and then the 10th.

I really can't see why and how to solve it..

Thank you in advance for any clues/comments which could be helpful !

Comment: This is a typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your complications arise because of the strange design of nested maps. Why don't you simply use a single map, for example `std::map<std::pair<int,int>,float>`?

Comment: @Walter no, it's your *answer* that's the XY problem. There's nothing wrong with using nested maps, even if there's an easier way of doing things - it shouldn't cause a crash.

Comment: Have you tried to insert the new inner value pair **without** giving the hint? That is `pi_matrix.at(lj).insert(std::make_pair(li,1.f));`

Comment: Have you checked whether the error occurs in `numb_lj[it_lj->first]` or in `max_pi[it_lj->first]`? As you failed to produce a MVCE, I cannot tell. Perhaps replace `[i]` here with `.at(i)` to check for access violation.

Comment: @Walter if the hint is incorrect it shouldn't matter, it's just an optimization - the correct insertion point should always be used regardless of the hint.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your design of a nested `map` is causing all sorts of unnecessary complications. More natural appears a single map with a `pair<int,int>` as key:

```
using key_type = std::pair<int,int>;
using map_type = std::map<key_type,float>;

void add_to_map(map_type&map, key_type const&key)
{
    map[key] += 1.f;   // also works as desired if map.count(key)==0
}

// find key and value of first element with maximum value
map_type::value_type find_max(map_type const&map)
{
    auto max = map.begin();
    for(auto it=max; it!=map.end(); ++it)
        if(it.second > max.second)
            max = it;
    return *max;
}
```

no need to juggle with `map::count` or `map::iterator`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Indeed it was simpler .. I rewrote it with your method, it does what it's suppose to do but, once again, crashes with a segmentation fault after few iterations..

Comment: We agree that everythig i'm using here will be detroyed at the end of the function as i'm not using any "new" ?

Comment: @mbuffier Which function? You don't have a function! So nothing will be destroyed. I though that this map is a member of a class, and hence its lifetime that of the corresponding class object.

Comment: @mbuffier Please post and [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it stands, we cannot really help you. Moreover, the post is useless for others, so is liable to being closed. From your remark, it appears that the bug is not in the usage of `map`, but elsewhere (as I suggested in the comments to the question).